# Third party library integration

Tags: layout

Hi i am trying to integrate third party library in magento. I put it the folder in lib  and my path is lib/surange/abrahim. the autoload sits inside surange. I made an observer inside custom model. the code is below

```
<?php
class Rkt_CustomBlock_Model_Observer
{
/**
 * @param Varien_Event_Observer $event
 */
public function controllerFrontInitBefore(Varien_Event_Observer $event)
{
    self::init();
}

static function init()
{
    // Add our vendor folder to our include path
    set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . Mage::getBaseDir('lib') . '/suranga');

    require_once(Mage::getBaseDir('lib') . '/suranga/autoload.php');

}

}
```

Few things I need to know. How do i access my library from web browser. for example like this localhost/magento/index/twitter. Second which other file do i need to modify for it? my observer have all the paths to the module. 
any help is appreciated as I am new to magento. My library name is abrahim/twitterAutho

Answer (score 3):

First of all, I want to congratulate you for asking a good question.

I can see that you are going in correct direction and I just want to "smoothen" your path with this answer.

The most important thing which is relevant here is understanding Magento autoloader. You want to integrate a third party package with Magento and you put it in the `lib` folder. Even if you did that, Magento is not going to "recognize" your package, unless you have configured your package in ***[Zend File Naming Convention](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/coding-standard.naming-conventions.html)***. This is because Magento autoloader is based on Zend File Naming Convention.

Magento autoloader will look for a file in `local`, `community`, `core` codePools and then finally in `lib` folder. The files and class-names of the files which resides in these folders are following Zend File Naming Convention. Otherwise Magento autoloader can't parse the requested class and the corresponding file.

So I recommend you to look into packages in `lib` folder and make a good understanding on how those third party packages are distributed and named. You need to convert your package in that same manner so that Magento autoloader can recognize your package files.  Then you can invoke your package classes in "Magento Way"

Another solution exist there is, you can use a custom autoloader to manage your package and then include your custom autoloader into Magento. For that ***[refer this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6417394/how-to-add-a-3rd-party-library-to-magento)*** (second solution) and you will get some more idea about your problem.

Comment: I am having hard time understanding this code. you know my folder structure, how do i use str_replace for it if ( preg_match( '#^(Solarium|Symfony\\\\Component\\\\EventDispatcher)\b#', $class ) ) {
            $phpFile = Mage::getBaseDir('lib') . '/' . str_replace( '\\', '/', $class ) . '.php';
            require_once( $phpFile );
        }